# Replace comparation with capital letters on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to replace with capital letters in this input text, for example I want to put on bold the letters which they are de same on the input, but if is capital letters doesn't put on bold

this is my line of code `$texto_option = $texto_option.replace($(input).val(),'<b>'+$(input).val()+'</b>');`

[image: Here you can see my problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a regular expression that ignores the letters' case:

```
var search = $(input).val();
var re = new RegExp(search, "i");
$texto_option = $texto_option.replace(re, "<b>$&</b>");
```

This is an easy answer. But keep in mind that your input has to be sanitized, as some characters are control characters for regular expressions too:

```
search = search.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
```

Comment: wow that solved 99% of my problem, thank you so much but I would like to have the first capital letter, could you help me ?

Comment: @PaulNoris Sure, I edited the answer so now it prints out the captured string rather than the inserted one.

Comment: You don't need to escape all those characters in a character class. `[-[\]\/{}()*+?.\\^$|]` I think would work.